# Calculate running total using unbounded preceding

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on writing a query which will give the number of hours left on starting day and it should gradually decrease towards end day and reach zero.

I tried using unbounded preceding function. It helped but not completely.

```
SELECT project_id,
       sprint_id,
       est_task_per_sprint,
       start_date,end_date,
         nvl(sum(est_task_per_sprint) over (
           order by end_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding

       ),0) tot
FROM   project_sprint where project_id=1;
```

The `sum(est_task_per_sprint)=1134` is the total hours.

Output I got:

```
Proj  Sprint  Hours  startdate  enddate    hoursremaining
   1       1    262  01-JAN-19  31-JAN-19               0
   1      11    263  01-FEB-19  28-FEB-19             262
   1      21    266  01-MAR-19  31-MAR-19             525
   1      31    262  01-APR-19  30-APR-19             791
   1      41    261  01-MAY-19  31-MAY-19            1053
```

Expected:

```
Proj  Sprint  Hours  startdate  enddate    hoursremaining
   1       1    262  01-JAN-19  31-JAN-19            1053
   1      11    263  01-FEB-19  28-FEB-19             791
   1      21    266  01-MAR-19  31-MAR-19             525
   1      31    262  01-APR-19  30-APR-19             262
   1      41    261  01-MAY-19  31-MAY-19               0
```

Comment: You are looking for **remaining** hours, so window clause should be `rows between 1 following and unbounded following`. But it does not return exact values, they differs [slightly](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b980a469934efddfc42acbfefcbeaaf0).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the remaining hours by subtracting the the sum of the hours up to - and including - the current row (*not* 1 preceding) from the total of all hours for the project.

I've added partitioning by project ID so this will work without the ID filter too, and as the window now matches the default (rows between unbounded preceding and current row) I've left that clause out. This example includes the total and completed hours to make it clearer - they aren't needed in your real query.

```
SELECT project_id,
       sprint_id,
       est_task_per_sprint as hours,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       sum(est_task_per_sprint) over (partition by project_id) as total,
       coalesce(sum(est_task_per_sprint)
                  over (partition by project_id order by end_date), 0) as completed,
       sum(est_task_per_sprint) over (partition by project_id)
         - coalesce(sum(est_task_per_sprint)
                      over (partition by project_id order by end_date), 0) as remaining
FROM   project_sprint
--WHERE  project_id=1
ORDER BY project_id, start_date;

PROJECT_ID  SPRINT_ID      HOURS START_DATE END_DATE        TOTAL  COMPLETED  REMAINING
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        262 2019-01-01 2019-01-31       1314        262       1052
         1         11        263 2019-02-01 2019-02-28       1314        525        789
         1         21        266 2019-03-01 2019-03-31       1314        791        523
         1         31        262 2019-04-01 2019-04-30       1314       1053        261
         1         41        261 2019-05-01 2019-05-31       1314       1314          0
```

which is the same as summing *later* rows, this time using a window clause of rows between 1 following and unbounded following:

```
SELECT project_id,
       sprint_id,
       est_task_per_sprint as hours,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       coalesce(sum(est_task_per_sprint)
                over (partition by project_id order by end_date
                      rows between 1 following and unbounded following), 0) as remaining
FROM   project_sprint
--WHERE  project_id=1
ORDER BY project_id, start_date;

PROJECT_ID  SPRINT_ID      HOURS START_DATE END_DATE    REMAINING
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        262 2019-01-01 2019-01-31       1052
         1         11        263 2019-02-01 2019-02-28        789
         1         21        266 2019-03-01 2019-03-31        523
         1         31        262 2019-04-01 2019-04-30        261
         1         41        261 2019-05-01 2019-05-31          0
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=37b11d444eda3632ed6ff3daeb5e2e28)

Notice that the numbers don't exactly match your expected result, but that's because I believe that your expectation wasn't quite right, and was based on the numbers your query produced - just reversing those doesn't make sense though.